# Some Categories are Showing up All Products - How to Fix This?

Tags: admin, category

This is the display setting of one of a category that is listing all products instead of showing only products that are assigned to it.

```
Display Mode = Products Only
CMS Block = Please select a static block ...
Is Anchor = No
```

***edit:***

**Category Products** tab has only 1 product assigned to it.

***edit2:***

this is the code that is showing all the products: 
(app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml)

```
<div class="category-products">
<ul class="products-grid">

<?php
//echo $_category->getId();
$_cat = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
$curent_cat = $_cat->getCurrentCategory();
$curent_cat_id = $curent_cat->getId();
$parentId=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($curent_cat_id)->getParentId();

$categoryid = $parentId;//$_category->getId();

$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->load($categoryid);
$collection = $category->getProductCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

//echo "<pre>";print_r($collection);echo "</pre>"; die();

$i=0; foreach ($collection as $_product) { ?>
<li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>"><img class="product-image" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" alt="" /></a> <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></a></h2>
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
<div class="actions">
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <ul class="add-to-links">
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
<?php $i++; } ?>
</li>
<?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
</ul>
 <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
  <div class="toolbar-bottom">
        <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>

</div>
```

Comment: did you try to rebuild your indexes and clear the cache?

Comment: cache is disabled.

Comment: not sure how to rebuild indexes. Btw, one thin i've noticed, i.e. when i create new category with no products assigned, it also shows all the products from all the categories.

Comment: `System->Index management`. Select all, rebuild index. It may take a while.

Comment: tried, but no use.

Comment: @Marius i have added the code that is displaying all the products, maybe there is something wrong in here?

Comment: Is the category an Anchor category and does it have subcategories with products in them?

Comment: @philwinkle no.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use `new`, Magento has factory functions to allow rewriting of components:

   - `Mage::getModel()`
   - `Mage::getSingleton()`
2. If I understand your code correct (`$categoryid = $parentId;`) you are iterating over the parent category. Remove this line and it should work.
3. Your code is messy and contains lots of things which are better placed in the block class. [Have a look into the original code](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml).
4. Don't edit `frontend/base/default` and `adminhtml/default/default`. These are base templates. If you want to make modifications, you need to create   your own theme, copy the templates you want to change to `frontend/yourThemeName/default`, e.g. `frontend/yourThemeName/default/catalog/category/view.phtml` and edit it there. Then activate your theme in the backend `System > Config > Design > Package(?) > yourThemeName`.

Comment: thank you for the code, i still the see all products after removing `$categoryid = $parentId;`. But if i replace it with this line `$categoryid = $_category->getId();` then i see fine but this change affects all categories that have sub-categories and shows no products at all.

Comment: I have just realized that if a category has sub-categories, then it works fine and do not show all products. But if a category has no sub-categories then it shows all products.

Comment: It sounds like your template is totally broken :)

Comment: ok, how can i find out if a category has any child categories? thx

Comment: in the template? $this->getCategory()->getChildren() and mybe there is a method hasChildren() But I recommend to have a look on the original template and fix the mess!

Comment: correct, i used `$this->getCurrentCategory()->hasChildren()`. And made a check if current cat has any sub-cats then use broken code otherwise use original code. And it seems its working for now. Many thanks for the help! :)

Comment: I'm sure this brings performance issues, but good that it works